# How to remove Youtube watermark on iOS app that plays Youtube videos?

Tags: ios, youtube-javascript-api, youtube-data-api, youtube-iframe-api

I want to display YouTube videos, in my iOS app, but I don't like the Youtube watermark-like overlay (that displays when paused) in the lower right corner.

This question has two parts:

1) I want to figure our how to suppress its display i.e. remove or hide the overlay - technically and

2) Would it breach their TOS?

My current view on TOS

There has been some views that it might violate YouTube's TOS, but I do not believe that to be the case because the app by this company - PlutoTV (plutotv.com) does not have the Youtube logo, nor do they have any indication that the videos are coming from YouTube. It might be possible that they are using their own player to play YouTube videos but either way they are streaming videos directly from Youtube onto their app.

Please advise!

Thank you.

Comment: You shouldn't ask multiple questions within 1 question. But to answer your second question. Just read it

Comment: I have read the TOS - but I presume it wouldn't apply to a player that was not a Youtube player. What I am asking is - what is Pluto TV's legal angle? they have $15.5M in funding, and over a million downloads. So they must be doing something that they are pretty confident does not violate the TOS.